# xtext domainmodel project doesn't recognize JVM types

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, xtext

1. I just created project based on xtext examples project "domainmodel".
2. Generated xtext artifacts from xtext file
3. Started eclipse application with plugins loaded
4. Created test project and then created test.dmodel file in it
5. I put inside code from documentation. Exactly this and only this:

   import java.lang.Object;

   package a.b.c.d {
   }

   entity aaa {
       prop1 : Object

   ```
   op oper1(Object obj1, Object obj2):Object {
       int i = 1;
   }
   ```

   }

But then:

- java.lang.Object,
- Object,
- int i

are not recognized. I thought that it will work out-of-the-box when xtext extends xbase instead of terminals and type is defined ad *Jvm*Type

Is this example broken or something?

Same thing is when I use home automation code from xtext documentation. All types from Jvm are not recognized as well as fire and println methods.
http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/307_special_languages.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure

1. The test project is a Java project
2. The test project has Xtext nature
3. Build automatically is enabled
4. The model files are in a source folder

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I just thought that if I create my own DSL I don't need Java Nature (as it will be used in our internal project type derrived from general project). And to put my file in src folder. So trivial yet so damn hard to think about. Thanks again! Kudos to you

Comment: Xtext nature is not required and build automatically also is not required.